# Please welcome your new Moderators!

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from this site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Joe Murray]
[image: Nicholai]
[image: Coleman]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they have contributed and no doubt will continue to contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Yes, almost certainly. There are many members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My inability to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.**

I may eventually be contacting additional users to fill more moderator slots, but I wanted to get a few folks activated before things really started to take off.

Comment: Congratulations guys! I'm sure you'll do a great job!

Comment: Hooray, finally! \o/ Looks like the site is in great hands!